# Clear all application data from a MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab

I'd like to clear all application data from a single figure, without using the names of individual application data variables.

Is there any function in MATLAB that will do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this in a simple way.

The application data for a figure is used to store lots of things by MATLAB itself (such as the zoom and pan status of the figure), not just things that you set yourself - so just "removing" it all is a bad idea.

You can get the full set of application data using `getappdata(f)`, where `f` is the handle to the figure (as opposed to the more usual `getappdata(f, 'varname')`, which would get a specific variable that you'd stored in the application data).

The result is a structure, and you can than go through the field names and delete anything you've stored.

To make this easier, you can use a consistent prefix for the names of any variables you store. Then just go through the field names and call `rmappdata` for any field that starts with your prefix.